# R: Looping through list of dataframes in a vector

Tags: r

I have a dataset where I only want to loop through certain columns in a dataframe one at a time to create a graph. The structure of my dataframe consists of data that I parsed from a larger dataset into a vector containing multiple dataframes.

I want to call one column from one dataframe in the vector. I want to loop on the dataframes to call each column.

See example below:

```
d1 <- data.frame(y1=c(1,2,3),y2=c(4,5,6))
d2 <- data.frame(y1=c(3,2,1),y2=c(6,5,4))
my.list <- list(d1, d2)
```

All I have to work with is my.list

How would I do this?

Comment: First off, you have a list of that consists of dataframes -- not a vector. Also, all the dataframes within the list should have the same column names.

Comment: Do you want to combine the columns from d1 and d2?  Or are trying to extract a subset of the columns from each of the data frames?

Comment: just want to extract a subset of the columns

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  Do you want to combine the subset into a single vector, or  a single data frame?  Or are you calling multiple graphs - one for each data frame

Comment: I am calling multiple graphs - one for each data frame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lapply` to plot each of the individual data frames in your list.  For example,

```
d1 <- data.frame(y1=c(1,2,3),y2=c(4,5,6),y3=c(7,8,9))
d2 <- data.frame(y1=c(3,2,1),y2=c(6,5,4),y3=c(11,12,13))
mylist <- list(d1, d2)

par(mfrow=c(2,1))

# lapply on a subset of columns
lapply(mylist, function(x) plot(x$y2, x$y3))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a for loop to get their data points. You can call the column by their column names.

```
# a toy dataframe
d <- data.frame(A = 1:20, B = sample(c(FALSE, TRUE), 20, replace = TRUE),
            C = LETTERS[1:20], D = rnorm(20, 0, 1))
col_names <- c("A", "B", "D") # names of columns I want to get
d[,col_names] # returns a dataset with the values of the columns you want
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution to your problem using a for loop:

```
# a toy dataframe
mylist <- list(dat1 = data.frame(A = 1:20, B = LETTERS[1:20]),
           dat2 = data.frame(A = 21:40, B = LETTERS[1:20]),
           dat3 = data.frame(A = 41:60, B = LETTERS[1:20]))
col_names <- c("A") # name of columns I want to get
for (i in 1:length(mylist)){
    # you can do whatever you want with what is returned;
    # here I am just print them out
    print(names(mylist)[i]) # name of the data frame
    print(mylist[[i]][,col_names]) # values in Column A 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest answer to your question is to use double brackets.

```
for (i in 1:length(my.list)) {

print(my.list[[i]]$column)

}
```

That works assuming all of the columns in your list of data frames have the same names. You could also call the position of the column in the data frame if you wanted.

Yes, lapply can be more elegant, but in some situations a for loop makes more sense.